# Adjusting axis-labels on radarchart (fmsb)

Tags: r, radar-chart

I have spent quite some time adjusting this radarplot, which will be used in about 200 auto-generated reports.
The only issue that i cannot seem to solve, is that the axis-labels overlaps with axis-marks. In the attached example, the issue is present in the left side of the plot.

Is there a way that i can decide where these axis-labels are placed? Or maybe place them in an angle, as you can in ggplot?

I would like to keep using fmsb if possible, as i really like the look of these charts.

I have placed a code below, that should give you [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ToK4.png). The image is saved as .png from R in size: w=1000 h=813

```
segmat <- 7
colors_border=c("#ee7f00", "#00aba4")
colors_in=c("#f6bf8099", "#73d1cd99")
legend <- factor(c("Skole", "Land"))
library(likert)
library(fmsb)

            datmat <- structure(list(`Data, Anvendelse` = c(80, 45, 76.9365245227314, 
            67.0674586834251), `Data, Viden` = c(80, 45, 73.8095238095238, 
            60.2180860386088), `Data, Ræsonnement` = c(80, 45, 65.6218434343434, 
            60.9232595763823), `Geometri, Anvendelse` = c(80, 45, 65.4590909090909, 
            52.8446335193598), `Geometri, Viden` = c(80, 45, 63.1238336316461, 
            55.0262048394226), `Geometri, Ræsonnement` = c(80, 45, 66.9981060606061, 
            50.2430105282051), `Tal, Anvendelse` = c(80, 45, 65.9269917792645, 
            53.701961851033), `Tal, Viden` = c(80, 45, 70.8290320790321, 
            65.5516016811992), `Tal, Ræsonnement` = c(80, 45, 57.5584072012643, 
            47.5568952748004)), row.names = c("1", "2", "Skole", "Land"), class = "data.frame")

        radarchart(datmat, axistype = 2,
                   pcol=colors_border , pfcol=colors_in, plwd=3 , plty=1, seg=segmat,
    vlcex=1.1, palcex=1.1,
                   mtext("Procentdel rigtige besvarelser for fagområder. Hver linje angiver en forskel på 5%", col = "darkgrey", font = 4, cex = 1.2),
                   axislabcol="black") 
        legend(1.0,-0.8,legend = reverse.levels(legend),
               col=colors_border,cex=0.8,
               pch = 16, lty =1 , lwd = 3) 
        title(main = list("Matematik", cex = 1.6, font = 4))
```

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I'm struggling with the same thing.

Comment: No, i never found a good solution, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with the same problem, and you can just copy paste the `radarchart()` code and edit it, to add that functionality.

Here's a monkey patch that quickly fixes it on the current version of `fmsb`.

```
patch_fmsb <- function() {
   fmsb.env <- environment(fmsb::radarchart)
   code <- deparse(fmsb.env$radarchart)
    
   # Axis label nudge
   code[60] <- "            text(xx[1:n] * r_nudge_caxislabels,  yy[1:n] * r_nudge_caxislabels, PAXISLABELS, col = axislabcol)"
   code[61] <- "        else text(xx[1:n] * r_nudge_caxislabels, yy[1:n] * r_nudge_caxislabels, PAXISLABELS, col = axislabcol, "
   
   # Variable label nudge
   code[68] <- "        text(xx * 1.2 * r_nudge_vlabels, yy * 1.2 * r_nudge_vlabels, VLABELS)"
   code[69] <- "    else text(xx * 1.2 * r_nudge_vlabels, yy * 1.2 * r_nudge_vlabels, VLABELS, cex = vlcex)"
   
   # Include parameters in function call
   code <- append(code, "    r_nudge_caxislabels = 1, r_nudge_vlabels = 1,", after = 5)
   
   rlang::env_binding_unlock(env = fmsb.env)
   fmsb.env$radarchart = eval(parse(text = code))
   rlang::env_binding_lock(env = fmsb.env)
}
```

And how to use it, for your example:

```
segmat <- 7
colors_border=c("#ee7f00", "#00aba4")
colors_in=c("#f6bf8099", "#73d1cd99")
legend <- factor(c("Skole", "Land"))

library(likert)
library(fmsb)

datmat <- structure(list(
   `Data, Anvendelse` = c(80, 45, 76.9365245227314, 67.0674586834251), 
   `Data, Viden` = c(80, 45, 73.8095238095238, 60.2180860386088), 
   `Data, Ræsonnement` = c(80, 45, 65.6218434343434, 60.9232595763823), 
   `Geometri, Anvendelse` = c(80, 45, 65.4590909090909, 52.8446335193598), 
   `Geometri, Viden` = c(80, 45, 63.1238336316461, 55.0262048394226), 
   `Geometri, Ræsonnement` = c(80, 45, 66.9981060606061, 50.2430105282051), 
   `Tal, Anvendelse` = c(80, 45, 65.9269917792645, 53.701961851033), 
   `Tal, Viden` = c(80, 45, 70.8290320790321, 65.5516016811992), 
   `Tal, Ræsonnement` = c(80, 45, 57.5584072012643, 47.5568952748004)), 
   row.names = c("1", "2", "Skole", "Land"), class = "data.frame")

patch_fmsb()

radarchart(datmat, axistype = 2,
           pcol=colors_border , pfcol=colors_in, plwd=3 , plty=1, seg=segmat,
           vlcex=1.1, palcex=1.1,
           mtext("Procentdel rigtige besvarelser for fagområder. Hver linje angiver en forskel på 5%", col = "darkgrey", font = 4, cex = 1.2),
           axislabcol="black",
           r_nudge_caxislabels = 1.05,
           r_nudge_vlabels = 1.05) 
legend(1.0,-0.8,legend = reverse.levels(legend),
       col=colors_border,cex=0.8,
       pch = 16, lty =1 , lwd = 3) 
title(main = list("Matematik", cex = 1.6, font = 4))
```

[image: radarchart]